# What is the difference between <chrono> and <ctime>?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, ctime

For measuring execution time of a function, I can use both. But what is the difference between using `<chrono>` and `<ctime>`? Should I prefer one instead of another?

Comment: Seconds vs nanoseconds?  Modern usability vs ancient semi-usability?

Comment: Vast change in ideology after 40-some years of use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ctime` is a C-style header, it's old, not type safe and not as accurate as `chrono`. `chrono` is the preferred option in C++; it's a contemporary C++ header, it's type safe, as accurate as our hardware allows, it has extended functionality, and, more importantly, it follows C++ (rather than C) logic so that certain things will be more natural/expressive with it and so that we may expect it to be aware of many contemporary language features (threads, exceptions, etc) - we cannot make the same assumptions for `ctime`.

That said, there are still several use-cases for `ctime` (or even `time.h`), e.g. when we need to talk with some C API or when we rely on old code-bases or when we use some library which follows a different kind of logic. C++ is designed to be pragmatic and not to be "pure" in any respect; this is why `ctime` and all sorts of antiquated headers, syntaxes and language features are still there even if programers are discouraged from using them.

Answer (score 4):

`ctime` is old school. Its only use now is as a crap solution to getting dates from time points (since c++ doesn't have an adequate standard datetime library). For general time needs, use `chrono`. If you need to turn a `system_clock::time_point` into a date/time, use `ctime`.

Comment: A better way than `ctime` to turn turn `system_clock::time_point` into a field date/time structure: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html :-)

Comment: @YeeLiu:  `ctime` is not "type safe".  For example `difftime` returns a `double` instead of a `duration`.  And `tm.tm_sec` has type `int` instead of type `seconds`.  This lack of type safety means that the compiler can't check logic errors which (for example) perform illogical algebra on units of time.

Comment: @YeeLiu Also the fixed epoch can be a nuisance. Another is the total blindness to threads. Allow me to moderate the total blindness to extremely nearsighted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Can you explain a little bit about blindness to threads ?

Comment: @YeeLiu A critical function `localtime` is not reentrant. This function is essential to any calendering conversions from time points